# Are their any software exist who support bookmark facelity for text file?

Tags: pdf, text, bookmarks

i have a big file in text format who i trying to read through Visual studio. i need only a feature that softare support Bookmark on specific line as well as PDF reader support last view page for pdf files.

When i bookmark in Visual studio and next time open the file i found that their is no boomark their.

so i have a question that a software who support text file and support bookmark for specific line in the project and many other feaure who make text reading better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you convert the text file to a pdf file?  On the mac you can do it for free.  In windows you can download the bullzip free pdf printer to do it.  Once its a pdf you can just use the pdf reader's boomarking ability.

Answer (score 1):

TRY Open Office.  
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ms-office/Word/Return_To_The_Last_Editing_Position_When_Opening_A_Document.htm